# Tips for Analyzing Circuit with Transistors

Tags: transistors, zener

Below is a circuit from a homework problem where I am asked to find the operating points of the three transistors. What I need help with is calculating the base currents for the transistors labeled T2 and T3. Could you please give me some hints as how I can find these currents?

[image]

Comment: Kirchoff's Current Law? Write down the formula for each node for 'incoming' and 'outgoing' currents. Then throw in I(C)=I(B)*f(FE) and I(E)=I(B)+I(C) and solve the equations.

Comment: You'll at least need to know the current-transfer ratio (hFE) of the transistors.

Comment: with `f(FE)` I meant `h(FE)`

Comment: I see you've accepted Olin's answer. In order to make this question useful to other users of the site, you should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: ... otherwise, it will be closed as "too localized"

Comment: I think we need horizontal and vertical image flip option and rotate CW and CCW options. I'm going to request them in meta.
Ex:- `[IMG ROTATE="90CCW"]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first thing to do is to redraw the schematic with a more logical layout.  Put positive power at top and negative power at bottom so that current mostly flows down the page.  Then arrange signals so their logical flow (more like cause to effect, not current flow) is left to right as much as reasonably possible.  Feedback signals are exceptions in that they should go backwards because that is their purpose.

When you follow basic rules of schematic layout, not only will the circuits become more clear but you will after a while recognize common subcircuits.  This is a good thing to get used to, and it will also help you get assistance from others that are more experienced.

The circuit as you show it looks like a mess to me because I have to think about what is connected to what and can't just "see" what is going on.  In this case, just rotating the whole thing right 90° is all it takes to fix it:

[image]

The writing is now sideways, but we can see the circuit from the schematic more readily.

Since this is a homework problem, I'm not just going to give you the answer.  However, I would start with a few simplifying assumptions.  For example, assume all transistors have "high" gain.  Analyze the circuit as if each had infinite gain.  They don't of course, but the difference between a gain of 100 and infinite shouldn't change the answer much.  Also good transistor circuits only need some minimum gain from each transistor and work all the way up to infinite gain.  This may sound like a difficult burden during design, but it's really not.  Look at most transistor datasheets and see that while minimum gain is specified, maximum is usually not.  Or if it is, it is a fairly sizable multiple of the minimum gain.  In other words real transistors vary a lot in gain, that has to be taken into account anyway.

Note that what logically follows from assuming infinite gain is that the base current is zero.  So for a first pass to see what is going on, your model of the transistors is that they drop let's say 600 mV from base to emitter and don't take any base current.  You should be now be able to figure out the base voltages of T3 and T2, and from that their emitter voltages, from that their collector currents, and from that the remaining voltages.

Now if you want to you can use that as a starting point and modify things assuming some finite gain, like let's say 50.  You will see that the various voltages and currents won't be all that different.  If this circuit actually used transistors with a minimum guaranteed gain of 50, then the two sets of numbers you get represent the limits of the operating range, with most real instances being somewhere in between.

Comment: Nicely written, but this approach doesn't work in this case, given how T1 is wired. Its behavior, and the drive to T2, very much depends on both transistors having finite gain. The numbers work out fairly neatly if you assume they have gain of 100, which may be what the professor intended.

Comment: @Dave: Yeah I noticed that after writing this answer.  I hadn't actually looked at the circuit before that.  However, I think assuming infinite gain to see where things are at, even if the circuit ultimately relies on some finite gain, isn't a bad way to start.  Even in this case, the voltages will be only slightly different from the infinite gain case.  In the infinite case, T2 is just plain off.  In the finite case, it will have a very small current thru it.  The voltage on R5 never exceeds that on R6, which will always be "small".

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP seems to have abandoned this question, here's my take on the solution.

First, I'm going to assume that the transistors have a B-E drop of 0.6V under all conditions, and that their current transfer ratio is 100. I'm also going to assume the Zener is "ideal"; i.e., the voltage across it is always 5.6V as long as any current is flowing through it.

Therefore, we can immediately label the base of T3 as being at 4.4V. Also, the emitter of T3 is at 3.8V.

The key question is what the voltage at the collector of T1 is. Let's call it V<sub>X</sub>. Observe that the emitter resistor of T2 can be considered to be a "virtual" resistor in series with the base with 100× the value, or 100kΩ (still through the B-E drop to ground). This, combined with the 40kΩ base resistor is functionally identical to the 140kΩ base resistor of T1.

Therefore, we can say that whatever current is flowing through R1, the same current is flowing through R3, 100× that current is flowing through T1, and 102× that current is flowing through R2.

We can now write down two equations and solve for V<sub>X</sub>:

$$I_{R1} = \frac{V_X - 0.6V}{140 k\Omega}$$

$$102 I_{R1} = \frac{4.4V - V_X}{7.4 k\Omega}$$

$$V_X = 1.195V$$

I<sub>R1</sub> = (1.195V - 0.6V) / 140kΩ = 4.25µA

Therefore, the collector current of T2 is 425µA and the collector current of T3 is 100/101 this value, or 421µA. The total current through the Zener is 103× I<sub>R1</sub>, or 438µA.

Comment: How do you determine T3's emitter voltage to be 3.8V?

Comment: Because its base is at 4.4V (10V - 5.6V) and, assuming T3 is conducting at all, the emitter must be 0.6V below the base. 4.4V - 0.6V = 3.8V.

Answer (score -5):

pretty simple, put it in your spice of choice and simulate..

Comment: I think they are looking at a way to solve it themselves By hand.